# Issue with listener.name.{listenerName}.ssl configurations in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set up a Kafka cluster that supports multiple ssl keystores and truststores depending on the listener.

I've set up a listener called "LOCALFWD", and configured it to point to a truststore, keystore, etc.

However, for some reason, every time I try to connect to it I get invalid handshakes and the usual "`ERROR [Logging] javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`" exception. Note that this happens both with hostname validation and without it.

**If I default to a single SSL configuration for all listeners, it works perfectly.**

I've tried to put the configs both in the server.properties file, statically, or alter them dynamically using kafka-configs, none of the options work.

Not sure what I am missing here?

Multiple listener config in server.properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,\
LOCALFWD://:9099,\

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,\
LOCALFWD://localhost:30090,\

listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,\
LOCALFWD:SSL

listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/tls-local/kafka.truststore
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/tls-local/kafka.keystore
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.keystore.password=kafka
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.truststore.password=kafka
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.key.password=kafka
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl.client.auth=required
```

Comment: FYI The reason for the LOCALFWD listener's existence is because I am deploying this in Kubernetes - it's so I can connect to the brokers using `kubectl port-forward` commands.

Comment: May be set `security.inter.broker.protocol` ?

Comment: I'm not trying to change the inter broker protocol security, but rather the LOCALFWD listener security - unless thats impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

Using lowercase in the listener properties did the trick:

`listener.name.localfwd.ssl` instead of `listener.name.LOCALFWD.ssl`

Listener, advertised listener, and listener security mapping remain  `UPPERCASE://`